# How to remove the text at the end of the sentence after the word 'at'?

Tags: text-processing, editors

I have a big data and looking for a `grep` command to remove the text and retain the job titles on this sentences, I already used this grep command `^.*?at` to get the company names after the word `at` but this time I want to retain their job titles, which `grep` command should I use?

```
CEO at Insurance Menu
Founder & CEO at insurtech
AVP, Alliances and Analyst Relations  at ValueMomentum
AGV-President at Aflac Ventures
```

The end result for e.g. the first line should be `CEO`, removing the entire text from the word `at Insurance Menu`

I am using BBEDIT (find & replace all) functionality.

Comment: You might want to look at answers here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ , specifically https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=BBEdit .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** In an edit to the question, it was detailed that the "Find and replace" option of BBEdit is to be used. This invalidates the original solutions proposed in this answer to some extent.

In order to remove the text after and including the `at` using BBEdit's "Find and replace" function, you can make use of the fact that the replacement text can contain backreferences to `(...)`-enclosed sub-patterns of the search pattern. So, for your purpose, you could use

```
(.*) at .*
```

as *Find* pattern (with `Grep` Option enabled), so that everything before the `at` is stored in a "capture group", and

```
\1
```

which is only the content of the "capture group", as *Replace* text. This works basically the same as the `sed` solution presented in the original version of the answer, below.

---

**Original answer**

Let's assume your input file is called `contact-details.txt`.

One approach might be to use `sed`, as follows

```
sed -E 's/(.*) at .*/\1/' contact-details.txt
```

This uses ERE (for convenience) and capture groups to replace (`s`ubstitute) the entire line by only the part in parentheses (the first capture group, denoted `\1`), which is the text before the (last) `at` on the line. It assumes there is only one occurence of `at`.

For your input example, the output would be:

```
CEO
Founder & CEO
AVP, Alliances and Analyst Relations
AGV-President
```

Another approach is using `grep` with [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) syntax enabled and "positive look-ahead":

```
grep -Po '.*(?= at )' contact-details.txt
```

This will match any text that comes before `at`, and thanks to the `-o` option *only* print that text, thereby discarding the `at` and anything after that. It has the same limitation that there must be only one `at` on the line for this to work.

Comment: Your original answer isn't invalid. There's a pic on the BareBones website showing how to run an `awk` command within BBEdit: https://www.barebones.com/images/bbedit/run-unix-command-lg.png . BBEdit (and it's predecessor TextWrangler) were (are?) popular HTML editors for the Mac. I recall TextWrangler even had a `#!` Menu Item. See: https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html .

Answer (score 1):

To delete the word `at`, flanked by a space on either side, and everything after it:

```bash
sed 's/ at .*//' file1.txt
```

Given the example text, this would produce

```
CEO 
Founder & CEO 
AVP, Alliances and Analyst Relations  
AGV-President
```

Comment: Apologies, my question was incomplete I've edited and added "I am using BBEDIT (find and replace all) function"